# Type-checking issue with io.TextIOBase in a Union

Tags: python, mypy

In the following code, I have a function that can take either a string, or some `TextIOBase`. If a string is passed, it is interpreted as a path to a file that should be opened and read. If a `TextIOBase` is passed, the contents of that stream will be read:

```
from typing import Union
import io

def function(foo: Union[str, io.TextIOBase]) -> None:
    if isinstance(foo, str):
        foo = open(foo, "w")
```

This seems like it should be okay, because Unions are supposed to be covariant, meaning that a subclass of one of the types in the union should satisfy the type annotation, and in this case the output type of `open()` is a subclass of `TextIOBase`. However, mypy complains with:

```
union.py:6: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "TextIO", variable has type "Union[str, TextIOBase]")
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I figured maybe there is an issue with the ambiguity of the return type of `open()`, based on the passed arguments, so I tried making a `StringIO` instead, but got the same error. Any thoughts? Why is mypy mad at me?

I have also tried this with some toy classes (e.g. `Union[str, T1]`, then assigning a `T2`, where `T2` is a subclass of T1), which mypy is perfectly happy with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `typing` module has a dedicated object for that: [`typing.TextIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TextIO). The return type of `open` is determined based on the `mode` argument and evaluates as one of these types: `TextIO`, `BinaryIO`.

Comment: That did the trick. I was wondering what `TextIO` was from the mypy message. Still seems odd that the type checking doesn't work for the honest-to-goodness classes themselves though. Why is `TextIO` in `typing` needed? The documentation for `typing` doesn't provide much in the way of context.

Comment: @youngmit I guess it's because the return type of `open` depends on its arguments, so you can't always determine what the return type is and need some kind of fallback (`typing.IO`). Imagine `open('test', mode=input())`; mypy will infer the type as `IO`. Hence, and in order to fulfill the subclass relationships with `TextIO` and `BinaryIO`, everything is defined in `typing`.