# Reconciling the differences between BinaryIO and RawIOBase

Tags: python, python-typing

My modest goal: Correctly annotate a function argument as an object supporting `read()` which returns `bytes`.

- If I use [`typing.BinaryIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.BinaryIO), I cannot accept a `serial.Serial` object (which derives from `io.RawIOBase`).
- If I use [`io.RawIOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase), I cannot accept a `BinaryIO` object (e.g. [`sys.stdin.buffer`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/ad9c7c1d0c842ac0cb3b010ecdd9402aac5f1bd3/stdlib/io.pyi#L157-L158))

```
import io
import serial
from typing import BinaryIO, Optional
import sys

def foo_rawiobase(infile: io.RawIOBase) -> Optional[bytes]:
    return infile.read(42)

def foo_binaryio(infile: BinaryIO) -> bytes:
    return infile.read(42)


def foo_serial(dev: serial.Serial) -> None:
    # error: Argument 1 to "foo_binaryio" has incompatible type "Serial"; expected "BinaryIO"  [arg-type]
    foo_binaryio(dev)

    # ok
    foo_rawiobase(dev)

def foo_file(f: BinaryIO) -> None:
    # ok
    foo_binaryio(f)

    # error: Argument 1 to "foo_rawiobase" has incompatible type "BinaryIO"; expected "RawIOBase"  [arg-type]
    foo_rawiobase(f)

def foo_stdin() -> None:
    foo_file(sys.stdin.buffer)
```

`typeshed` definitions:

- [`io.RawIOBase`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/ad9c7c1d0c842ac0cb3b010ecdd9402aac5f1bd3/stdlib/io.pyi#L78-L82)
- [`typing.BinaryIO`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/ad9c7c1d0c842ac0cb3b010ecdd9402aac5f1bd3/stdlib/typing.pyi#L704-L706)

How do I properly handle both cases?

Comment: I once wrote a similar question, maybe it contains some insight: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69570166/how-to-write-a-file-like-class-that-satisfies-typing-textio

Answer (score 1):

One solution to this is to use [PEP 544 – Protocols: Structural subtyping (static duck typing)](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/).

Use [`typing.Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) to define the required interface. Then, any compatible type can be used.

The [mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#defining-subprotocols-and-subclassing-protocols) even include this exact example:

```
class SupportsRead(Protocol):
    def read(self, amount: int) -> bytes: ...
```

Using `Protocol`, the above problem could be solved like this:

```
import io
import serial
from typing import BinaryIO, Optional, Protocol
import sys

class Readable(Protocol):
    def read(self, n: int = -1) -> Optional[bytes]:
        ...

def foo_custom(infile: Readable) -> Optional[bytes]:
    return infile.read(42)


def foo_serial(dev: serial.Serial) -> None:
    foo_custom(dev)

def foo_file(f: BinaryIO) -> None:
    foo_custom(f)

def foo_stdin() -> None:
    foo_file(sys.stdin.buffer)
```

(Note that `io.RawIOBase` declares the return type of `read` as `Optional[bytes]`, so I carry that forward here.)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to this is to accept a [`Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union) of both possible types. The type checker should properly deduce the type of `infile.read`.

```
import io
import serial
from typing import BinaryIO, Optional
import sys

def foo_union(infile: io.RawIOBase | BinaryIO) -> Optional[bytes]:
    return infile.read(42)


def foo_serial(dev: serial.Serial) -> None:
    foo_union(dev)

def foo_file(f: BinaryIO) -> None:
    foo_union(f)

def foo_stdin() -> None:
    foo_file(sys.stdin.buffer)
```

This prevents inappropriate use of methods or attributes that are present on only one of the input types:

```
def bad_use(infile: io.RawIOBase | BinaryIO) -> str:
    # error: Item "RawIOBase" of "Union[RawIOBase, BinaryIO]" has no attribute "name"
    return infile.name
```